Porque esta Funcion preg_mach siempre devuelve 0
Estoy tratando de obtener un nombre de un texto que es una constante con la funcion preg_match y es el siguiente.
"0233 4746 ERICK YOVANY BECERRA RIOS C. SAN LUCIO 1 #2 FRACC. REAL DE SAN GABRIEL Mexico Número de factura: RW-E0000092 Fecha de creación: 15/06/2024 Fecha de vencimiento: 20/06/2024 elemento Precio Cantidad Total SERVICIO DE INTERNET INALAMBRICO"
    require '../librerias/pdfparser/alt_autoload.php-dist';
    $parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
    $directorio = ('../recibospdf/prueba1_1.pdf');
    $pdf = $parser->parseFile ($directorio);
    $texto = $pdf->getText();
    $coincidir = ("/ 4746 (.*?) C. /i");
    $nom_client = preg_match($coincidir, $texto, $matches);
    var_dump($matches[1]); 
    echo $texto;

al obtener el resultado de la variable nom_cliente siempre me arroja 0 es decir sin coincidencia
he estado probando en la pagina regex101 y ahí marca la coincidencia sin problema



El problema es que no le estás pasando el tercer parámetro a la función, donde te guardará los matches, tal y como dice el Manual de PHP:

matches
Si se proporciona matches, entonces éste se llena con los resultados
de la búsqueda. $matches[0] contendrá el texto que coincidió con el
patrón completo, $matches[1] tendrá el texto que coincidió con el
primer sub-patrón entre paréntesis capturado, y así sucesivamente.

Por ejemplo:
$texto="0233 4746 ERICK YOVANY BECERRA RIOS C. SAN LUCIO 1 #2 FRACC. REAL DE SAN GABRIEL Mexico Número de factura: RW-E0000092 Fecha de creación: 15/06/2024 Fecha de vencimiento: 20/06/2024 elemento Precio Cantidad Total SERVICIO DE INTERNET INALAMBRICO";
$coincidir = ("/ 4746 (.*?) C. /i");
$nom_client = preg_match($coincidir, $texto,$matches);
var_dump($matches);

Salida:
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(35) " 4746 ERICK YOVANY BECERRA RIOS C. "
  [1]=>
  string(25) "ERICK YOVANY BECERRA RIOS"
}

Si te interesa el nombre, lo tienes en $matches[1].

he editado el código ya que olvide mencionar que la cadena la estoy obteniendo a través de una librería que se llama pdfparser y la cual obtiene en la variable texto, el contenido del PDF cuando se hace una impresión de variable muestra correctamente la cadena
